# How to parse the folder path from a WMI process?

Tags: regex, powershell

I need to be able to parse the folder path (which could vary) from an installed Windows service.

In PowerShell using

```
$serviceToRemove = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -Filter "name='Labelary'"
```

I can get the object, and if I do

$serviceToRemove.PathName

it gives

```
c:\program files\myapplicationname\mybinary.exe //rs/labelry
```

I need to get

```
c:\program files\myapplicationname
```

I've tried various combinations of splitting, but the path could vary or have spaces in it.

Is there a regex way of getting this portion of the path. The only guaranteed pattern is that I want the portion of the string which is before the wildcard *.exe . But I don't know how to express this in PowerShell. I tried `\w*\.exe` in a regex tester but this just returns the `mybinary.exe`.

Also various combinations of PowerShell or `System.IO` path tools seem to consider the `//rs/labelry` to be part of the path and thus not return the root correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$path = if ($serviceToRemove.PathName -match '[a-z]:\\.*?(?=\\[^\\]+\.exe)') {
    $matches[0]
}
```

The regular expression matches a drive letter (`[a-z]:\\`) plus the shortest sequence of characters before a backslash followed by an executable name (`\\[^\\]+\.exe`). The positive lookahead assertion (`(?=...)`) ensures that the backslash and executable name are not included in the returned string.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably write it this way:

```
$pathName = Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -Filter "Name='Labelary'" |
  Select-Object -ExpandProperty PathName |
  Select-String '^"?(.+)\.exe' | ForEach-Object {
    Split-Path $_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value -Parent
  }
```

Comment: Updated answer to account for potential `"` character and output using `Split-Path`. Pretty easy to read and maintain...

Comment: For that approach I'd include the extension in the capturing group, so that you extract the full path and can split it into directory path and file name, should the need arise.